# Freeglut doesn't initialize when using it from Swift

Tags: swift, pointers, opengl, glut, freeglut

I've tried to use the Freeglut library in a Swift 4 Project. When the

```
void glutInit(int *argcp, char **argv);
```

function is shifted to Swift, its declaration is

```
func glutInit(_ pargc: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!, _ argv: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!)
```

Since I don't need the real arguments from the command line I want to make up the two arguments. I tried to define `**argv` in the Bridging-Header.h file

```cpp
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

char ** argv[1] = {"t"};
```

and use them in main.swift

```swift
func main() {
    var argcp: Int32 = 1
    glutInit(&argcp, argv!)  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    glutInitDisplayMode(UInt32(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH));
    glutCreateWindow("my project")
    glutDisplayFunc(display)
    initOpenGL()
    glutMainLoop()
```

but with that I get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x74)` at the line with glutInit().

How can I initialize glut properly? How can I get an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!` so that it works?

Comment: I'm not a Swift guy, but it sure looks like it ought to be "char * argv[1] = {"t"};" rather than "char ** argv[1] = {"t"};" (note the single star rather than the double).  Not an answer since I'm just guessing...

Comment: When I delete one `*` then it won't even compile because the argument is wrapped in two UnsafeMutablePointers which is represented by the two `*` I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the right code in C `char * argv[1] = {"t"};` does not work is because Swift imports fixed size C-array as a tuple, not a pointer to the first element.

But your `char ** argv[1] = {"t"};` is completely wrong. Each Element of `argv` needs to be `char **`, but you assign `char *` (`"t"`). Xcode must have shown you a warning at first build:

> `warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'char [2]'`

You should better take `incompatible pointer types` warning as error, unless you know what you are doing completely.

Generally, you should better not write some codes generating actual code/data like `char * argv[1] = {"t"};` in a header file.

---

You can try it with Swift code.

As you know, when you want to pass a pointer to single element `T`, you declare a `var` of type `T` and pass `&varName` to the function you call.

As `argcp` in your code.

As well, when you want to pass a pointer to **multiple** element `T`, you declare a `var` of type **`[T]`** (**`Array<T>`**) and pass `&arrName` to the function you call.

(Ignoring immutable case to simplify.)

The parameter `argv` matches this case, where `T == UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?`.

So declare a `var` of type `[UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?]`.

```
func main() {
    var argc: Int32 = 1
    var argv: [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?] = [
        strdup("t")
    ]
    defer { argv.forEach{free($0)} }

    glutInit(&argc, &argv)
    //...
}
```

---

But I wonder if you really want to pass something to `glutInit()`.

You can try something like this:

```
func main() {
    var argc: Int32 = 0 //<- 0

    glutInit(&argc, nil)
    //...
}
```

I'm not sure if freeglut accept this, but you can find some articles on the web saying that this works in some implementation of Glut.